# What is the hierarchical DB schema for this xml?

Tags: database-design, xml, relational-database

As per this [link](https://github.com/shamhub/books/tree/master/xml), this is the xml that maintains "BookStore" data.

I see that number of occurences of author are varying for any book.

xml's hierarchical representation of `BookStore` looks more meaningful/intuitive for me to visualise the data unlike relational table tuples. It is rather more difficult(kind of tweek) to map such hierarchical information in tables.

It is strange to see that real world(hierarchical) data(for example, SNMP MIBs of network devices or BookStore etc...) are mapped to tables of records in many commercial softwares. For me, it is not-intuitive(rather unnecessary skill) to convert such hierarchical data to tables, despite relational DB(like MSSQL) support massive/safe/multi-user/convenient/efficient/reliable unlike  xml file format.

So, we are trying to fit hierarchical ordered data into table tuples which is an overhead. Do we have any commercial database that companies use to maintain schema in hierarchical fashion?

*Note: am currently part of database course.*

Comment: Have you had a look at NoSQL databases ?

Comment: I guess, NoSQL is in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to maintain a hierarchy in a relational database, you need to look into the Nested Set design pattern.  ([See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model))

This model involves some programming, and it involves some overhead at insert or update time.  The benefit comes at retrieval time.  Retrieving the path or the subtree for any given node is easy and fast, when compared to the traditional approach, called *Adjacency List*.

Comment: Can i get a resourcelink for any java practice application that use this pattern and store in relational DB?

Answer (score 1):

Hierarchical databases used to be very popular, but they went out of fashion in the 80s because they are not very good at supporting ad hoc querying, and setting them up could be difficult, I believe. The best known standard for hierarchical databases was the CODASYL data model (see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CODASYL for details of this), which was integrated into the COBOL language. Commercial implementations are still available, but I don't anyone does new work in it any more.

A more modern equivalent is the document-store database, of which mongodb is the most popular. Mongodb stores and handles queries about documents in BSON, which is a data format roughly equivalent to JSON in capability. This means that while not all xml can be easily mapped to it, a lot can, including the examples you link. See http://bsonspec.org/ formore detail about  BSON.

Comment: thanks for this info, i will further look into it, because am about learn JSON now ):

Comment: Using relational, i saw a table schema design that maintains tree hierarchy structure of nodes in a hierarchical network as a tuple `(parent_node,child_node,ancestor_rank)` so for multiple parents you have a single child and ancestor_rank will prefer which parent to choose. You additionally maintain indexes for faster retrievals from such tables. But this is tough design and non-intuitive in practical world. This is the crux of my query. i will check your answer further in this aspect.

Comment: The big downside of MongoDB is that it doesn't support transactions (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Some (much?) data, such as the book example, isn't inherently hierarchical. That the bookstore example uses hierarchical storage is a consequence of XML's tree structure, not the inherent structure of the data. Consider that a book can have many authors, and an author can write many books, which means neither can strictly belong to the other. XML gets around this by using identity attributes by which one node can reference another; the same technique is used in other serializations of circular data structures.

A full relational model can deal with truly hierarchical, homological data using [closure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Closure.html) properties; specifically, the [transitive closure](http://planetmath.org/TransitiveClosure) allows tree paths to be retrieved using a parent-child relationship. The real problem is that SQL and most production RDBMSs don't support closure properties in general. Transitive closures are available in SQL with [Common Table Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression)/the `WITH RECURSIVE` clause but are relatively new in implementation and don't seem to get used as much (and aren't supported by all RDBMSs). More typically, you see the full path stored in the table ([Farey Fractions](http://arxiv.org/html/cs.DB/0401014) can be considered paths using their decimal expansions and special markers for repeated trailing digits, similar to [quote notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quote_notation)).

Another data model you used to see often was the [network model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_model), where nodes are datums and edges are relationships. In the book model, there'd be an edge from each author node to each book node for a book that the author wrote. The database reports & specifications created by CODASYL used a network model. There are various issues with using a network model that the relational model specifically addresses; [Codd's seminal paper](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf) has more.

If the relational model seems non-intuitive, perhaps it's because you have yet to grok the relational model. Don't think of it as tables and rows (which are more what you find in a spreadsheet) but as declarative relationships:

```
Hector Garcia-Molina wrote "A First Course in Database Systems"
Jeffrey Ullman wrote "A First Course in Database Systems"
"Database Systems: The Complete Book" is a book with ISBN '0-13-815504-6' and price $85
...
```

From there, you write the statements using [predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29):

```
Wrote(Hector Garcia-Molina, "A First Course in Database Systems")
Wrote(Jeffrey Ullman, "A First Course in Database Systems")
Book("Database Systems: The Complete Book", ISBN:0-13-815504-6, price:$85)
...
```

Note that the `Book` example isn't a simple predicate because two of the datums are tagged with names; this is part of what distinguishes a relationship from predicates, relations and other similar mathematical objects. Predicates define sets, so you can use set operations to define new relationships. This brief overview is very informal and imprecise, but should give you a starting point.

Comment: i think you are talking about this [recursion](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/DB/Recursion/SelfPaced/about) correct?.

Comment: @overexchange: yes, but be warned that the examples use the [outdated comma syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/894490/90527), which confuses filters and join conditions. There are various reasons not to use it; personally, I've seen bugs resulting from its use.